# How to detect user tapping into status bar from iOS Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, mobile-safari

Is there any way to detect whether a user browsing my website is tapping / expanding the status bar? Is any sort of javascript "out of focus" event fired?

We want to use this for alerting the user before navigating away during an ongoing transaction. window.onbeforeunload is apparently not supported by Mobile Safari.